# Strings not being treated the same - Python

Tags: python

So i a making a caesar cipher program that uses a keyword. However when i make my program ask for the keyword again for decryption the keywords are apparently treated differently even if i enter the exact same characters.

my first input for a keyword is:

```
keyword = input("Please enter a keyword")
keyword = keyword.upper()
keyword = keyword.replace(" ","")
```

my second input is:

```
keyword2 = input("please enter the keyword again")
keyword2 = keyword2.upper()
keyword2 = keyword2.replace(" ","")
```

For some reason even if i enter the same characters i get them being counted as different when i test it. This is the only part of my program that changes the keyword variable. The rest of it just grabs the first letter for example.

Al

Comment: can you show your input and output  ?

Comment: Print out your keywords and see what they output. Also you don't show us where you compare them.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing your input or where you compare them, but I'd guess you're using **is** where you should use **==**. See [Why does comparing strings in Python using either '==' or 'is' sometimes produce a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce) for more info.